# Google Sheets Python batchUpdate repeatCell -> issue with range and number format

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, format

I am trying to use the google sheets api for python to format only a specific columns results to a "NUMBER" type but am struggling to get it to work properly. Am I doing something wrong with the "range" block? There are values that are getting appended to the column and when they get appended (via a different api set) they do not come back as formatted numbers that, when highlighting the entire column, result in a numbered sum.

```
id_sampleforstackoverflow = 'abcdefg123xidjadsfh192810'
cost_sav_body = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 2,
          "endRowIndex": 6,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 6
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "numberFormat": {
              "type": "NUMBER",
              "pattern": "#.0#;#.0#"
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
      }
    }
  ]
}
cost_sav_sum = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=id_sampleforstackoverflow, body=cost_sav_body).execute()
```

So when I run the above with the rest of my code, the values get appended, however, when highlighting the column, it simply gives me a count of the objects, and not a formatted number summing the total of the values (i.e. there are three values of -24, but only see a "Count" of 3 instead of -72).

I am using the GCP recommendations api for machineType to append the cost projection -> costs -> units value to the column (they append for example like i.e. -24).

Can someone help?

Documentation I have already gone through:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/formatting-cells-with-the-google-sheets-api
  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats
  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange

Answer (score 0):

@all

> I was able to figure out the problem. When doing straight reporting of the values for the cost (as explained above as an objective) I was converting the output to string using the str() python method. I removed that str() method and kept the rest of the code you see above and now things are posting correctly:

```
#spend = str(element.primary_impact.cost_projection.cost.units)
spend = element.primary_impact.cost_projection.cost.units
```

So FYI for anyone else wondering, make sure that str() method is not used if you need to do a custom formatting code to those particular cells!